# Angular ngx-translate dynamic translation

Tags: angular, internationalization, ngx-translate

Is it possible to get translation to a key without splitting it to different keys, based on predicate?
For example, my json file:

```json
"some_text" : "{{predicate}} ? 'translation1' : 'translation2'",
```

code:

component.ts

```js
dynamicData(predicate: boolean) {
    this.translate.get('some_text', { predicate: predicate }).subscribe((s: string) => {
      this.result = s;
    });
return this.result;
```

.html:

```html
<span [innerHTML]="dynamicData(true)"></span>
```

I expect to get 'translation1' on screen.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can achieve this with ngx-translate without splitting your translation into different keys.

Since you can neither use a ternary expression nor a `translate.set()` call in the JSON file, I doubt this is feasible. Maybe I'm wrong, in which case I would be interested in knowing how to do it, if anyone in the comments can tell me.

**Even though this is not exactly what you asked for**, I would have done it like this:

*json file*

```json
"some_text_true" : 'translation1',
"some_text_false" : 'translation2',
```

*component.ts*

```js
dynamicData(predicate: boolean) {
    this.translate.get(predicate ? 'some_text_true' : 'some_text_false').subscribe((s: string) => {
      this.result = s;
    });
    return this.result;
}
```